# How do the sizes of the various proposed manned capsules differ?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, roscosmos, boeing, lockheed-martin

How do the overall dimensions, internal volume, mass of the various manned capsules being developed compare?

```
Apollo (as a good baseline)
Orion
Dragon
Dragon V2
CST-100
Soyuz
```

For bonus points, ISS cargo vehicles.

```
Cygnus
ATV
HTV
Progress
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: Dragon (v1) isn't a manned capsule. Only Dragon v2 will be.

Comment: What about the Soviet Space Shuttle Buran?

Comment: @EugenioArpayoglou it wasn't a capsule. Only rocket bits that go on the top of stages and can take people count.

Comment: @NateBarbettini: Dragon was originally planned to gain the ability to carry a crew. SpaceX even built a full-scale mockup. https://twitter.com/spacex/status/232146433833320449

Answer (score 32):

Found a couple of good photos of at least three of the vehicles side by side.

CST-100 - Orion - Dragon

[image: CST-100 - Orion - Dragon]

Graphic of Apollo - Orion - CST-100 - Dragon

[image: Apollo - Orion - CST-100 - Dragon]

A great picture from User3, who found it on reddit, showing the various vehicles all side by side to scale.

[image: Side by side of manned vehicles]

Another good one, doing a better job of showing manned vs reentry vs service modules parts.

[image]

Great summary of the various vehicles with sizes and internal volumes:

https://lasttechage.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/the-web-of-privatized-space-1-crew-and-cargo/

Not to forget the [Indian Orbital Vehicle](http://www.astronautix.com/craft/orbhicle.htm), here it is laid out next to some other vehicles.

[image: From Astronautix.com]

[image: From Astronautix.com]

Then for the granddaddy of them all, how much of the shuttle is really crew space.  (Really just a portion of the nose)>

[Shuttle Crew Cabin](http://www.scientificindians.com/images/crew_cabin.gif)
[image]

A [good infographic from Space.com](http://www.space.com/12725-russia-progress-cargo-spacecraft-infographic.html) has this image:
[image]

That shows the relative sizes of Progress, Soyuz, ATV, and HTV at the bottom, overlain on a space shuttle.

This [great Space.com infographic](http://www.space.com/15429-spacex-dragon-space-capsule-manned-infographic.html) includes Dragon, Progress, Shenzou, ATV, and Orion:
[image]

Comment: One could add the [Indian Orbital Vehicle](http://www.astronautix.com/craft/orbhicle.htm) which was test landed empty Dec.18,2014 [Link2](http://www.space.com/5967-designs-india-manned-spaceship-revealed.html) It's 2.0 m diameter (if correct) is smaller than the crowded Soyuz' 2.2 m.

Comment: And maybe an [illustration](http://www.scientificindians.com/resources/photo-gallery/endeavour%E2%80%99s-final-mission-the-last-blast) of the size of the crew cabin of the space shuttle.

Comment: "how much of the shuttle is really crew space" Wow, I had no clue it was so tiny as crew space goes.

Comment: Shuttle was quite spacious -- especially when you added SpaceLab.

Answer (score 13):

Here's one more comparison of relative sizes of manned vehicles. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ad7C.jpg

[image]

Comment: Oooh!  I like that one!  Mind if I steal and merge it into my answer? I like how the manned component is drawn on the line, so you get a simple view of how big each trunk/service module is as well. (Shuttle notwithstanding).

Comment: Had not realized how small Dream Chaser was compared to the Shuttle.

Comment: Please do. I merely found this on the space subreddit this morning, and the clever person behind the picture is http://www.reddit.com/user/Tanchistu . Yeah, the Shuttle is pretty darn big.

Comment: It needs a second line in some cases.  For example, Mercury's graphic includes the LAS.   Voskhod's shows the airlock.  Dream Chaser isn't all habitable.  Nice start though.

Comment: @Erik I think Dream Chaser is ok, this is not about habitably but the bits that come back. Good call on the rest.